# Pass auto direct page after login to the webpage

Tags: html, perl, httprequest, lwp

I have successful login to a webpage by the script below but the webpage stuck at the redirect page. I has no idea how to pass through it. Below is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $URL="http://www.redirect.com";
my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$UA->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 ); 


my $req =HTTP::Request::Common::POST("$URL",
Content_type=>'form-data',
Content =>[
     'username'=>'name',
     'password'=>'pass',
]
);



my $resp=$UA->request($req);

if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $res2 = $UA->post($resp->base, []);
    open(OUTFILE1, ">html1.txt"); 
    print OUTFILE1 $res2->decoded_content;

    if ($res2->is_success) {

        if( ($resp->code() >= 200) && ($resp->code() <400) ) {

            open(OUTFILE, ">html.txt");
            binmode(OUTFILE, ":utf8");    
            print OUTFILE $resp->decoded_content;

        }else{
            print "Error: ". $resp->status_line. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part of the output file i get

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>

        </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request.<BR>
    <BR>You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below.
    <FORM NAME="AUTOSUBMIT" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Continue"></FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

How to pass through this auto direct page to reach the website i want? Have modified according to the answer but nothing was output.

Edit 8/7/2017

I try the way `simbabque` suggest and debug by print out the `$res2` in `html1.txt`. The output look like below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
        <title>302 Found</title>
    </head><body>
        <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a 
        href="http://www.redirect.com">here</a>.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I have no idea what this mean. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are missing  a `>` in your output for the opening `FORM` tag. Is that really missing, or did you lose it while copying?

Comment: That's a proper 302 response. It tells you it was redirected. Your LWP user agent should follow that automatically.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque, if success why the program not enter the `if($res2->is success)` loop? The code will not print the `html.txt`.

Comment: @simbabque, the final result i need is to print out the content inside the `www.redirect.com` . How can i do it? Your help is much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part about this is probably the headers. A *normal* website would issue a redirect status code, like a [302 Found](https://httpstatusdogs.com/302-found). But that's clearly not the case here, or they wouldn't need this rather strange HTML thing.

The HTML has built-in JavaScript execution.

```
<BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">
```

It tells the browser to submit the form directly when the page has loaded. Your problem is that LWP::UserAgent cannot do that, because it doesn't have JS support.

But since this always happens, it's trivial to code around it. All you need to do is submit that form every time you log in.

```
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success) {
    my $res2 = $ua->post($res->base, []);
    if ($res2->is_success) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The form has no parameters. The only `<input>` element there is is the submit button, and since that doesn't have a `name` attribute it does not show up as a parameter. The URL is likely the same as the one you submitted originally, but it might have done a real redirect already, so it's better to use the `base` attribute of the response object.

---

I do wonder why they make this process so weird. It certainly doesn't authorize anything. It might set additional cookies, like one of those marketing redirect thingies, but that's not visible from what you've showed. And it does not stop automation either.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque , i edit my code follow your suggestion but is output. Did i modified correctly. I edit the code above.

Comment: @Tim did you update the output as well? You should try around with what to send in the second request. See if the URL is right.

Comment: Hi @simbabque, the second request has fail so the code will end without going in the if loop that print the output file.

Comment: @Tim did you try to debug it? Output the request as well as the response, look at the headers. Or use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere to have the whole communication dumped to the console, then compare it to what your browser is doing where it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have try to debug it and edit my question as above. The `$res2` print out is different with the `$resp` and i dont know what it means.